# Change system wide PHP version on CPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to install the SilverStripe CMS on CPanel but it complains that the PHP version needs to be updated to at least 7.1. From the control panel I can access a "PHP Selector" to change the version of every domain to 7.2, but nowhere to change the version of the server which is currently set to 5.6.35.

Error message:

> Required PHP version greater than equal to 7.1.0 AND found version is
>   : 5.6.35

Server info:

```
hostnine_business
Server Name ams3
cPanel Version  70.0 (build 69)
Apache Version  2.2.31
PHP Version 5.6.35
MySQL Version   5.6.41-84.1
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux
```

I have read about a tool called "MultiPHP" which I don't seem to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option of MultiPHP comes in WHM , you can access the WHM panel only when you have root access. If you are on a shared hosting , then contact your hosting service support and ask them to change it.